# How to add a column with duplicate sequence number for spark dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need add a column to a spark dataframe, which should be duplicate sequence number, such as `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ..., 10000, 10000, 10000]`. I knew that we can use `monotonically_increasing_id` to get the sequence number as new column.

```
val df_new =  df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

Then, what is the solution to extend this function to get the duplicate sequence number? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate a row number, divide that by 3, cast to integer type, and add 1:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df_new = df.withColumn(
    "id", 
    (row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id))/3).cast("int") + 1
)
```

Comment: Nice solution but I think `monotonically_increasing_id` does not always start from 0.

Comment: doesn't matter, the row number starts from 1 always